# array must be declare error in pl sql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error

I want to return a array in a function as my function looks like below,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST  
RETURN t_array 

IS 
strings t_array;

BEGIN
--do something
RETURN strings; 
END:
```

But it gives a error t_array must be declare. I want to know where to declare it and how can i declare it?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a custom type, you have to declare that type first. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_array IS TABLE OF varchar2(50);
```

Which creates a new type named string_array that is a table of varchars.
For more information check the official oracle dokumentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm)

Comment: You could also declare the array in a package, but it must be defined somewhere to be used in a method's argument list.

Comment: If i want it as a common function rather put it inside a package, then how should i declare it?

Comment: As you want the custom type as the return type, it has to be declared outside of your function as far as I know. So just declare the type as you would declare a new table or function... e.g. in SQL Developer just do it on a SQL Worksheet.